# How to fix "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to edit users details and also trying to update in a database table.So i login with username and password then i am getting all the users details on redirected page.but i am unable to edit details also unable to update in a database.Where do i need to change the functionality in my code.
In a database table field DOB is taking value through calendar.same with LastDonated Field.

I have tried the below code to achieve my output result.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\BBMS\BloodBank\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE DonorRegist SET FullName='{1}', Gender='{2}', DOB='{3}', BloodGroup='{4}',Weight='{5}', Email='{6}', Country='{7}', State='{8}',City='{9}', Address='{10}', Pincode='{11}', ContactNo='{12}', LastDonated='{13}',DonorPassword='{15}' WHERE UserName='{14}'", txtdonorname.Text, rblgender.SelectedValue, txtDOB.Text, ddlBG.SelectedValue, txtbodywt.Text, txtdonoremail.Text, ddlCountry.SelectedValue, ddlState.SelectedValue, ddlCity.SelectedValue, txtdonoradd.Text, txtpin.Text, txtdonorcontact.Text, txtlastdonate.Text, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text), con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I expect the ouput as when i edit some field value it should get updated in a corresponding database table.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `String.Format` expects you to start with 0 as index:

```
string.Format("UPDATE DonorRegist SET FullName='{0}' ...", conn);
```

But you can simplify it with string interpolation:

```
new SqlCommand($"UPDATE DonorRegist SET FullName='{txtdonorname.Text}', ...", conn);
```

And even better - if you would use sql parameters - that way you can save yourself from SQL injections!

```
cmd = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE DonorRegist SET FullName=@donorName, ...", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@donorName", SqlDbType.String);
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = txtdonorname.Text;
```

Finally - last recommendation is to use `using` - to avoid forgetting to dispose of your used resources, in your instance - `SqlConnection`